# How to re-filter a sequence asynchrounously in Rx

Tags: vb.net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an observable sequence that should be filtered using the `Where` operator based on some criteria, and should populate a list with those filtered elements.

I want to change the filtering criteria on the fly, so when this happens, the list should be cleared, the previous elements of the observable sequence should be evaluated for the new criteria, as well as new elements produced by the sequence.

The list should be repopulated with past elements which now passes the new criteria, continuing with new elements (filtered as well). I don't care that new elements might be delayed, while previous elements are re-evaluated, but i do care about order.

Is this something that can be done with Reactive Extensions?

[image]

Comment: When should the observable pipeline emit a List ? When is the List "completed" ?

Comment: The pipeline should not emit a list, it should only populate one. The list is a regular  `List(Of T)` that should be populated when elements emitted by the initial observable passes through the pipeline. When the filter criteria is changed, the list should be repopulated with previous elements that now matches the new criteria, as well as with new elements as they arrive taking into account  the new filtration criteria as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice extension method that does what you need:

```
public static IObservable<T> Refilterable<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<Func<T, bool>> filters)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<T>(o =>
            {
                var replay = new ReplaySubject<T>();
                var replaySubscription = source.Subscribe(replay);
                var query = filters.Select(f => replay.Where(f)).Switch();
                var querySubscription = query.Subscribe(o);
                return new CompositeDisposable(replaySubscription, querySubscription);
            });
}
```

I tested this with this code:

```
var source = new Subject<int>();
var filters = new Subject<Func<int, bool>>();

var subscription = source.Refilterable(filters).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

source.OnNext(1);
source.OnNext(2);
source.OnNext(3);

filters.OnNext(x => x % 2 == 0);

source.OnNext(4);
source.OnNext(5);

filters.OnNext(x => x % 2 == 1);

source.OnNext(6);

filters.OnNext(x => x % 3 == 0);

source.OnNext(7);

filters.OnNext(x => x % 2 == 1);

subscription.Dispose();

filters.OnNext(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

I got this output:

```
2
4
1
3
5
3
6
1
3
5
7
```

Which seems to be what you're after.

---

I just noticed the requirement to produce lists. Here's an update:

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> Refilterable<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<Func<T, bool>> filters)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<IList<T>>(o =>
            {
                var replay = new ReplaySubject<T>();
                var replaySubscription = source.Subscribe(replay);
                var query =
                    filters
                        .Select(f =>
                            replay
                                .Synchronize()
                                .Where(f)
                                .Scan(new List<T>(), (a, x) =>
                                {
                                    a.Add(x);
                                    return a;
                                }))
                        .Switch();
                var querySubscription = query.Subscribe(o);
                return new CompositeDisposable(replaySubscription, querySubscription);
            });
}
```

The only other thing I noticed was the VB.NET tag. I'll see if I can convert later if need be.

---

This should be the right VB:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function Refilterable(Of T)(source As IObservable(Of T), filters As IObservable(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As IObservable(Of IList(Of T))
    Return Observable.Create(Of IList(Of T))( _
        Function(o)
            Dim replay = New ReplaySubject(Of T)()
            Dim replaySubscription = source.Subscribe(replay)
            Dim query = filters.[Select](Function(f) replay.Synchronize().Where(f).Scan(New List(Of T)(), _
                Function(a, x)
                    a.Add(x)
                    Return a
                End Function)).Switch()
            Dim querySubscription = query.Subscribe(o)
            Return New CompositeDisposable(replaySubscription, querySubscription)
        End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: The first one is correct, requirement is not to emit lists but to populate one.

Comment: @Enigmativity I really like your solution, although i have a question involving concurrency. Regarding the first approach, when my source has been emitted many values, the `ReplaySubject` has been buffered all those. Then when the filter source emits a new filter, a `Where` operator is applied to the `replay`.  What happens with a new value emitted by the source while the `Where` operator is executing.  Does the `ReplaySubject` uses an internal queue for each of it's subscribers ?

Comment: The Rx "contract" requires all operators to serialize events w.r.t. each subscriber. i.e. An operator should guarantee never to call the OnNext of a given subscriber concurrently. The internal library functions honor this and do it by the equivalent of per-subscriber queues. However, the implementations expect all upstream operators to honor this contract to work. The `Subject<T>` class notably doesn't enforce serialized calls to `OnNext` and abuse of this can cause unexpected behavior. See the Rx guidelines here for more about expected behavior: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219

Comment: @JamesWorld - Would you suggest adding a `.Synchronize()` call to ensure that the subject behaves?

Comment: I usually make that judgement on a case by case basis -  sometimes you just "know" that you won't need it - if there's any doubt I usually do include it. The only real reason I can think of not to is performance (which is why the original Rx team didn't make it intrinsic). I'll wager that the performance is rarely enough of an issue to leave it out.

Comment: @francezu13k50 - I hope James' comment answered your question. I've updated my answer with a subject-safe version and added VB.

Comment: A few notes here. 1) This wont clear out the list when the filter changes and gives no hook to do so, unless the consumer also hooks up to the filter obs (the original answer) 2) the follow up answers only return a list, and return the whole list every time. So  3) The `replay` variable could be added to the returned `CompositeDisposable`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something crucial, the specified requirements eliminate the need for immutable collections and simplify the implementation because you need to buffer all emitted values.

```
private List<T> values = new List<T>();
private IObservable<T> _valueSource;
public List<T> ValidValues => values.Where(MatchesCriteria).ToList();

private void StartSubscriptions()
{
    var addNewValuesSub = _valueSource.Subscribe(values.Add); //todo disposing
}
```

If you believe that `IEnumerable.Where` is too slow and we know all possible criterias beforehand. We could `GroupBy` separate values to their respective `Observable`s / data structures. It would look something like this.

```
_valueSource.GroupBy(CriteriaSelector)
            .Subscribe(i => UpdateDataStructure(i.Key(), i.Latest()) );
```

`IObservable` is not good for buffering lots of values which should later be accessed by some criteria. That's a job for `IEnumerable`.

Finally, if you think memory usage will be an issue consider refactoring `values` as a memory object caching system.

Comment: I will indeed use an ImmutableList, and it will be a very large list whith possible million items. I don't want to drop items that didn't matched the criteria, i need to buffer all items somehow. When the filtration criteria changes, those buffered items should be re-evaluated. Also if i do the re-evaluation as you sugested, while the list is evaluated, new values that arrive will be put to the list, but that list will be overwriten(by reference assignment) when the `.ToImmutableList()" returns, and those values will be lost forever.

Comment: @francezu13k50 from the OP it seemed to me you want to drop items that don't match the current criteria. Can you tell us more specifically what you mean by re-evaluating buffered items?

Comment: Yes in a sense i want do drop them, but not to loose them forever, because if i change the criteria, and those dropped items should have  matched the new criteria, they should be brought  back to the list. In order to do this i think that they must be buffered somehow. I added a diagram  to better ilustrate what i need.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer based on the specified requirements

Comment: The `GroupBy' is a good suggestion, although at this point i don't know if i'll be able to do that. It might be necesary to filter by an unique indentifier which can't be known beforehand.  What do you mean by "refactoring values as a memory object caching system" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have two initial reactions

1. That is just a .`Replay()` that is resubscribed to when the filter condition changes
2. That also sounds like an unbounded buffer :-/

To address my first thought, you could just have this code

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IDisposable _replayConnection;
    private readonly IConnectableObservable<int> _replaySource;
    private readonly SerialDisposable _subscription = new SerialDisposable();
    private readonly List<int> _values = new List<int>();

    //the Ctor or some initialise method...
    public Foo(IObservable<int> source)
    {
        _replaySource = source.Replay();
        _replayConnection =  _replaySource.Connect()
    }

    public void SetFilter(Func<int, bool> predicate)
    {
        //Not thread safe. If required, then a scheduler can solve that.
        _values.Clear();
        _subscription.Disposable = _replaySource.Where(predicate)
            .Subscribe(value => _values.Add(value),
                ex => {/*Do something here to handle errors*/},
                () => {/*Do something here if you want to cater for completion of the sequence*/},
    }
}
```

However, this just makes me more concerned about point *2*. If you are expecting millions of values, then if they are just ints, then it is about 3MB/1mil items of memory you will be using. If they are ints, then copy by value semantics, you will get copies in the Replay buffer and in your final list (IIRC). If this kind of memory pressure is ok, then I think the `Replay` code above will be fine. Also note that this Replay usage will throw if you try to buffer more than `int.MaxValue` values.

Comment: Nice one, but what are your opinions on using an `IObservable` for this purpose instead of an `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The question is about an observable sequence that needs to be replayed when a predicate changes. It populates an `IEnumerable`, and internally a Replay subject would use some sort of `IEnumerable`, but otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: What I meant to ask is: do you think Rx is the best solution here? But then again, it was requested by OP so let's settle with the answers presented.